# Lightning Shadow effect in CORONA SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am trying to create a spotlight effect in my story book such that as the character moves around from one location to the other then the light focus moves towards that same character.Is it possible to do that in Corona SDK? How can I do that coz sprites aren't
 helping me.Any idea regarding this.
I found some reference telling me that I can't do that

http://web-c2.anscamobile.com/forum/2012/10/27/dynamic-shadows-2d

http://developer.coronalabs.com/forum/2012/09/13/lightingshadows

Answer (score 0):

Those two threads seem pretty definitive.  You could create a spotlight pretty easy, but you can't cast shadows and the light moves different directions very easily.

If you want to do a spotlight without shadows, just create an image that's all black with a transparent hole in them middle that has some feathering around the hole.  Make the black partially transparent so you can see the scene but have it a bit darker.  You can them move the image around to be your spot light.  You can also do it with a maskk (see the Flashlight example in the sample code)